# $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\lim_{x\to 0}( 1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx))^\frac{1}{n^3x^2} )$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, summation, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left( 1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)^\frac{1}{n^3x^2} \right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left( 1+\sum_{k=1}^n(k^2x^2)\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{k^2x^2}\right)^\frac{1}{n^3x^2}\right)$$$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left( 1+\sum_{k=1}^n(k^2x^2)\right)^\frac{1}{n^3x^2}\right)$$$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left( 1+x^2\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\right)^\frac{1}{n^3x^2}\right)$$$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left( 1+x^2\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)\right)^\frac{1}{n^3x^2}\right)$$$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2}}$$$$=e^\frac13$$

This is how I solved it and the answer is correct according to the answer key provided, yet I am a bit uncomfortable with the solution. That is because when I multiply and divide $\sin^2(kx)$ by $k^2x^2$, I know that $\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{k^2x^2}$ will equal to $1$ if $k^2x^2$ tends to $0$, which is true for all finite values of $k$ where $x \to 0$. However, the expression I get from it is being used to calculate the limit when $k \to n$ where $n \to \infty$, but, as I said, $\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{k^2x^2}$ will equal to $1$ if $k^2x^2$ tends to $0$, which is true for all **finite** values of $k$. So how is this valid?

Comment: You can't argue like that. As $x$ also does appear as a power, you cannot use $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$ like that. Additionally, when you evaluate the limit $x\rightarrow 0$ in the end, after that there can't appear any $x$ anymore, i.e. we have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} (1+x^2f(n))^{1/x^2n^3} = e^{f(n)/n^3}$, where $f(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ without the $x$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: Indeed the step you have used is not allowed in general, even if the final result is correct.

Comment: Then can someone post a legal way of solving this as an answer please?

Comment: @stange thanks, i think i corrected the second point you mentioned in my edit

Comment: I think your problem is not whether your solution is valid or not. Actually, what you want to tell is if we can say that $\lim_{n\to b}(\lim_{x\to a}f(n,x))=\lim_{x\to a}(\lim_{n\to b}f(n,x))$, and it is of course impossible to do so. You may need strong regularity condition to make it valid, which makes sense you also can not directly have a well-defined meaning of taking the limit at the same time, say $\lim_{n\to b, x\to a}f(n,x)$. Such limitation probably can not be defined under regular meaning for you may get different result when approaching it by different argument.

Comment: And for your inner limitation, you can also strictly deduce $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin^2(kx)=\frac{n}{2}-\frac1{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(2kx)=\frac{2n+1}{4}-\frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{4\sin x}$$ where using $2\cos(2kx)\sin x=\sin(2k+1)x-\sin(2k-1)x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you transform $\frac{\sin u}{u}\overset{?}{=}1$ inside the limit which may *or may not* lead to a correct answer. Because the *rate* at which $\sin u/u\to1$ matters and it may be that other factors in the limit, e.g. the exponentiation to the power $1/n^3x^2$, changes the behaviour. As a very basic counterexample, consider: $$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u-u}{u^3}$$You might be tempted to do this: $$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u-u}{u^3}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin u}{u}-1}{u^2}\overset{??}{=}\lim_{u\to0}\frac{0}{u^2}=0$$But in fact the limit is $-\frac{1}{6}\neq0$.

*Fix* $n\in\Bbb N$. We can apply L'Hopital's rule twice, or use asymptotic notations: $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{n^3x^2}\ln\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2n^3x}\cdot\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot\sin(2kx)}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)}\\&=\frac{1}{2n^3}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot\sin(2kx)}{x}\\&=\frac{1}{n^3}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\cdot\cos(2kx)\\&=\frac{1}{n^3}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\end{align}$$

You may object: it looks like I just treated “$\sin(kx)=0$” there (replacing $1+\sum\sin^2$ with $1$), seemingly contradicting what I said at the start. But here I know for certain it’s ok to do so because there is an easy theorem: if $f(x)\to a$ and $g(x)\to b\neq0$ as $x\to c$ then $f(x)/g(x)\to a/b$ as $x\to c$.

Therefore: $$\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)^{\frac{1}{n^3x^2}}\underset{x\to0}{\longrightarrow}\exp\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}\right)$$For any $n\in\Bbb N$.

So you have: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}\right)=\exp(1/3)$$

Comment: thank you so much! Just one thing though, how did I eventually end up at the correct answer by the wrong means? Is it just coincidence or is there something particularly peculiar with the function that the error was ignored?

Comment: P.S: I would have solved $\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u-u}{u^3}$ using Taylor expansion anyways so lol can you provide another example please?

Comment: FShrike, you should write $\,\color{red}{u^2}$ instead of $\,u^3$ in your basic counterexample :$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u-u}{u^3}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin u}{u}-1}{\color{red}{u^2}}\overset{??}{=}\lim_{u\to0}\frac{0}{\color{red}{u^2}}=0\;.$$

Comment: @Angelo Whoops, typo

Comment: @AltercatingCurrent The answer you arrived at was correct because in this instance, the difference between $\sin^2(kx)$ and $(kx)^2$ was asymptotically too small to leave an impact. But you did not carefully assess this beforehand, it may have been, in a different problem, the case that this error term changes the value of the limit. I will try to find less basic counterexamples

Comment: But hopefully you see the point. It’s inconsistent to say, “oh *sometimes* I’ll use Taylor expansion (which is always correct if you do it carefully) but sometimes I won’t, I’ll just use $\sin x/x=1$.”

Comment: @FShrike yes i do see your point, thanks

Answer (score 4):

*Just for the fun of finding the next term.*

$$A=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin^2(kx)=\frac{1}{4} (2n+1-\csc (x)\, \sin ((2 n +1)x))$$ Expanding around $x=0$
$$A=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) x^2-\frac{1}{90}n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right)x^4+O(x^6)$$
Adding $1$ and taking the logarithm
$$\log(1+A)=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) x^2-$$
$$\frac{1}{360} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(10 n^3+27 n^2+17 n-4\right)x^4+O(x^6)$$
$$B=\frac{\log(1+A) } {n^3\,x^2}=\frac{(n+1) (2 n+1)}{6 n^2}-$$
$$\frac{1}{360 n^2}  (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(10 n^3+27 n^2+17 n-4\right)x^2+O(x^4)$$
$$e^B=e^{\frac{(n+1) (2 n+1)}{6 n^2}} \left(1-\frac{(n+1) (2 n+1) \left(10 n^3+27 n^2+17 n-4\right)}{360 n^2} x^2+O(x^4) \right)$$

Then the limit and a bit more.

Comment: Good work! I have upvoted your answer! I like it so much! Please, could you also calculate :$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)^\frac{1}{n^3x^2}\right]\;\;?$$

Comment: @Angelo. Thanks for the kind words. The one you give is ptobably .... very difficult, not to say more.

Comment: Actually I believe the limit first as $n\to\infty$ is always $1$, independent of the value of $x$. Because $\ln(1+\sum\sin^2)\le\ln(1+n)\le n$ and $n/n^3x^2\to0$. @Angelo